# Converting "\\u1234" to "\u1234"

Tags: boost, unicode, utf-8, fstream

I have a string that I have retrived from an html page using boost's regex_search(). Unfortunately, however, the japanese characters in the page are written as \u codes, and these are interpreted by regex_search as normal characters in a string.

So, my question is, how does one go about converting these codes to normal Unicode text? (UTF-8 obviously)

This is a fundamental issue with fstream having absolutely no regard for UTF-8. It looks like boost has its own implementation of fstream, but changing to it had no effect on my program, and I couldn't find any extra settings to configure boost's fstream to work with UTF-8 (although today is my first day ever working with boost, I could have missed it).

As a final note: I'm running this on linux, but I'd certainly appreciate a portable solution over a system-specific one.

Thanks all, I really appreciate the help :D

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates the issue, and an example of the data that you’re seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fstream` is a narrow-character only stream (it's a typedef to `basic_fstream<char>`). `std::wfstream` would be the type you're looking for, although to be perfectly portable to, for example, Windows, you may have to introduce C++11 dependencies (Windows has no Unicode locales, but supports locale-independent Unicode conversions introduced by C++11. GCC on Linux doesn't support the new Unicode conversions, but has plenty of Unicode locales to choose from) or rely on boost.locale.

Your steps would be:

1. parse the string to obtain the hexadecimal values of the code points
2. store them as wide characters.
3. write them to a `std::wofstream` (or convert to UTF-8 first, and then write to `std::ofstream`)

To illustrate the last step:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.utf8")); // any utf8 works
    std::wofstream f("test.txt");
    f.imbue(std::locale());

    f << wchar_t(0x65e5) << wchar_t(0x672c) << wchar_t(0x8a9e) << '\n';
}
```

produces a file (on Linux) that contains `e6 97 a5 e6 9c ac e8 aa 9e 0a`